# problems with using sticky footer with two sepperate footers

Tags: css, html, sticky-footer

I'm currently self teaching myself Web development. and i am recreating a website from the ground up. it should look something like this:

> ===========nav bar=============
>
> =========website body===========
>
> ===========footer #1============
>
> ===========footer #2============

and my basic code structure is:

```
<body class="main-body">
  <form id="form1">
    <footer id="footerContainer">
      <div class="ContainerBlock">
        <section class="big-blue">
          <div class="Container">
            <div class="rows">
              <div>(these are columns)</div>
              <div>(these are columns)</div>
              <div>(these are columns)</div>
              <div>(these are columns)</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section class="copyrights">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="rows">
              <div>
                <small>copyright text</small>
              </div>
              <div>
                <a href="a link!!!">
                  <img alt="im an image" src="im an image"/>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section> 
      </div>
    </footer>
  </form>
</body>
```

footer 1 is a list of page links set out in columns and footer 2 is a copyright message and some interactive images. footer 1 is a solid blue block and i need it to rest on top of the solid white block of the footer.

i have tried using:

```
.footer
{
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

and (this is what it is currently set to):

```
.footer
{
position: relative;
bottom:0;
}
```

and:

```
.footer
{
position: fixed;
bottom:0;
}
```

and:

```
#footer
{
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

i've fiddled with changing the position of my sections and footers. i've played with changing padding values, but no matter what i do it sits resolutely in the middle of the page.

if i set both of my footers to:

```
position:relative;
bottom: 0;
```

then footer 1 crushed footer 2 and looks like junk.
what is a clean way to get both to stick to the bottom of my page, no matter how long it is, without crushing my copyright info?

Comment: Please add code snippet to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`.footer` refers to elements whose class is `footer`

`#footer` refers to elements whose id is `footer`

`footer` refers to footer tags

Try

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: this, unfortunately, doesn't change its position for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.
Why you use a form tag if you don't need a form?
So If you want all your footer fixed at the bottom of the page you must add this code:

#form1{
                position:fixed;
                bottom:0
         }

If the 3 columns are floated you need to use clearfix like this [clearfix-hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)